# Does $\int\frac{1}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\,dx$ have a closed form?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, neural-networks

Context: I am looking for an [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) that is linear in the area surrounding $x=0$, while also staying within the range of -1 to 1. While I was messing around in Desmos, I stumbled across the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)$.

$\int\frac{1}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\,dx$ produces the exact shape I am looking for, but I cannot figure out how to find the closed form for it.

Am I missing something obvious, or does this function not have a closed form antiderivative?

Comment: [WolframAlpha says no.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+tanh%281%2Fx%5E2%29)

Comment: @mrtaurho Yeah, that was the first thing I tried. 

Comment: There are many tractable approximations that will work just fine.  I wouldn't concentrate on that *particular* form.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one I can think of is
$\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}
$.

There are also
$\tanh(x)
$
and
$\arctan(x)
$
scaled as
$(2/\pi)\arctan(\pi x/2)
$.

Comment: I was specifically looking for a function $f(x)$ where $f''(x)\approx0$ for $-a<x<a$, where $a$ is a significant fraction of $1$.  

For example, in the case where $f(x)=\int\frac{1}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\,dx$, $f''(x)\approx0$ for $-0.4<x<0.4$.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know of any closed form, but here is a solution, out of a few possibilities, that has an interval of convergence with $|x|<\infty$ which uses [geometric series](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux7vl6zXxj0) and the [error and dawson integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html). This used [Wolfram Alpha aid](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=intergal+exp%28-2%2Fx%5E2%29%5En). Notice the n=0 term gives the partial sum of 0:

$$\mathrm{\frac12 \int tanh\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)dx=\frac12\int \frac{2}{e^{-\frac{2}{x^2}}+1}-1dx=\int \frac{1}{1- -e^{-\frac{2}{x^2}}}dx-\frac{x}{2}=-\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int \left(-e^{-\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)^n dx=C-\frac x2+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-\frac{2 n}{x^2}} x + \sqrt{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sqrt n \,erf\left(\frac {\sqrt{2n}}x\right)\mathop =^{x\in\Bbb R}
C-\frac x2 + \frac{x\,e^\frac2 {x^2}}{e^\frac2 {x^2} +1}+ \sqrt{2\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sqrt n \,erf\left(\frac {\sqrt{2n}}x\right)}$$

Another way which converges better is using [this sum representation if the hyperbolic tangent](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tanh/06/01/02/01/0003/) converging for |x|>$\sqrt \frac 2\pi$ Which uses the [Bernoulli Numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)
$$\mathrm{\frac12 \int tanh\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)dx=\frac12\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}\left(2^{2n}-1\right)B_{2n} \left(\frac1{x^2}\right)^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}= C+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}\left(2^{2n}-1\right)B_{2n}x^3\left(\frac 1 {x^2}\right)^{2n}}{(3-4n)(2n)!}\mathop=^{0<x\in \Bbb R}=C-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}\left(2^{2n}-1\right)B_{2n}x^{3-4n}}{(4n-3)(2n)!}}$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!